# How to validate data from flat file?

Tags: ssis

I using script component for validating data more 50 columns. But it take more time. Any body give solution for this validation without third party tool in ssis.

For example :

I have validate dob column in following points

1. Date format is correct or not.This my expecting format(mm/dd/yyyy).
2. DOB not equal to empty.
3. DOB value not greater than (12/31/9999).
4. DOB value also check is date or not.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Import your date data as a date data type. Let the SSIS magic validate whether it's a date. Within SSIS, use a derived column to determine whether the data matches your business logic (valid boundaries, data exists, etc)

Comment: Your right but i have received date from flate file following format (mm/dd/yyyy). how to set this format in flat file connection in advance tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have doubts about the fields in your excel file, you can import the data to a Staging Table, create the table with all the fields as varchar and insert the data from the file there, when the data is loaded you can work with an sql validation or with ssis components to verify the data, you should test which is faster.

**Edit 1:**
After this you can create functions to validate each field like:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[Validate_Field](
    @Code [varchar](2),
    @Code2 [varchar](2)
)
Returns VarChar(50) AS
BEGIN
    Declare @return Varchar(50)   
    SET @Salida = ''    
    IF @Code = '29' RETURN 'Something 1'    
    IF @Code2 = '21' RETURN 'Something 2'   
    ELSE RETURN 'Missing'   
    Return (@return)
END


SELECT [dbo].[Validate_Field](Field1, Field2)
FROM Staging_Table
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried in sql query used with inner case function . but it allowed only 25 inner case. how validate more then 70 columns in sql server.
CASE
   WHEN condition 
     THEN
         CASE
            WHEN condition1 
                THEN
                    ELSE calculation2
                    END
               END

Comment: Hi, i recommend you to use a function to do that, make it easy, make a validation function for each field if you think you need it with if clauses and then you won´t need the cases in the Select sentence

Comment: can you give some example for this?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the answer.